# How to update the navigation item list based on the content displayed

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular6

I have this navigation menu

```
<ul class="menu-left pl-3">
    <li *ngFor="let period of periods; let i = index">
        <a class="mb-4 fragment-link" [class.active]="selectedIndex === i"
           [ngClass]="{'text-dark font-weight-bold': selectedIndex === i}" (click)="setIndex(i)"
           [routerLink]="['/registrations/list']" fragment="d{{period}}">
            {{period}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the period is a school year e.g. `2017-2018`. 
In the page I want to add the dynamic scroll, I want the navigation item to be highlighted when the card that is shown to the user is in that school year. Users usually register for 2 semesters per school year ( sometimes for only one though), so binding a nav entry with one of the registration entries is not a solution.

Here is the pattern the cards follow:

```
<div class="reg_courses_body__main">
          <div *ngFor="let registration of registrations">
            <div id="d{{registration?.registrationYear.alternateName}}">
            <div class="card mt-2 year">
              <div class="card-body">
....
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      const scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('year');
      const periods = document.getElementsByClassName('fragment-link');
      let j = 0;
      for ( let i = 1; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        j = i;
        if ($(elements.item(i)).position().top - 70 <= scrollDistance) {
          continue;
        } else {
          for ( let k = 0; k < periods.length; ++k ){
            if( elements.item(i).parentElement.id === 'd'.concat(periods.item(k).textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ''))) {
              j = k;
            }
          }
          $('.menu-left li a.active').removeClass('active text-dark font-weight-bold').addClass('text-gray-600');
          $('.menu-left li a').eq(j).addClass('active text-dark font-weight-bold');
        }
      }
  }).scroll();
```

but it didn't quite work as I expected it.

Comment: Don't use jQuery with angular if you can avoid it... for this case it is just also soooo unneccessary.

Comment: Can you please elaborate where or how did you add this jquery?
it will be good if you will use HostListener event.
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(e) { }

Comment: I have added jQuery on the index.html header as as ` <script> ` and that minor script in the constructor of the component

Comment: Use @HostListener instead of <script>
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(e) {
//Your javascript 
}

Comment: @khushi thanks for the feedback. I successfully added the @ HostListener and know the menu refreshes as its supposed to. I will update the question with my implementation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `@HostListener` like this

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  public onWindowScroll(event: ScrollEvent): void{
    if ( !this.isScrolling ) {
      this.isScrolling = true;
    }
    const currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('year');

    for (let i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
      const currentElement = elements.item(i);

      if ($(elements.item(i)).position().top <= currentScroll) {
        this.selectedIndex = this.periods.indexOf(currentElement.parentElement.id.slice(1, currentElement.parentElement.id.length));
        $('.menu-left a.active').removeClass('active text-dark font-weight-bold');
        $('.menu-left a').eq(this.selectedIndex).addClass('active text-dark font-weight-bold');
      }
    }
  }
```

which fetches elements with the class `.year` and checks for their position in the page and if the position of an element is smaller or equal to the current scroll it updates the navigation menu, by removing the classes attached to the active element and attaches them to the active element. 
the `selectedIndex` is the index of the id of the parent of the current element minus the first letter because the ids of the elements where of this format `d{{period}}`.

Many thanks to @khushi for pointing me towards the correct direction